# How can I Log Error in a generated apk file

Tags: java, android, android-studio, apk

I have generated the apk for an android app but can't figure out how to keep track of the log files.
My app is running during build and run, however it's crashing when the apk file is generated.

I need help to track the error for the apk file.

Comment: You can make a .log file in app data folder and send that log files into api by daily bases

Comment: Have you tried using logcat to see the log output of your device/emulator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also using crash reporting tools like Crashlitycs would be a good choice.

You need to create an Account and put your API key in your app. Then initilize Crashlitycs and now on, everytime your app crash it will send a report and you can track them all even they are grouped by API level and App Version.

According to [this guide](https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics/install) the way to go is:

Add the Kit to Your build.gradle

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
  }

  dependencies {
    // These docs use an open ended version so that our plugin
    // can be updated quickly in response to Android tooling updates

    // We recommend changing it to the latest version from our changelog:
    // https://docs.fabric.io/android/changelog.html#fabric-gradle-plugin
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
  }
}
```

Then in your app level gradle:

```
// Put Fabric plugin after Android plugin
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
  maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
```

And add the dependency:

```
  compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.5@aar') {
    transitive = true;
  }
```

In your manifest, add INTERNET PERMISSION and add this meta with your API KEY:

```
  <meta-data
      android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
      android:value="<FABRIC_API_KEY>"
  />
```

Finally initialize Crashlitycs with:

```
  Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
```

Comment: thank you, this solution worked I added my Crashlytics and now can track the issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your logs and exceptions in a file and can check that file later
or can email/post on server that file

also you can add Log Events - Firebase - Google library inside your project thats a good approach to maintain the app in long term

https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/events